# Jquery accordion hide not active sliders

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, accordion

I am trying to hide accordion tabs which are not active and the last tab, however not much luck till now

Code I have till now:

```
                    $('#accordion > h3').each(function() {...});
                    var accordion, first, last, lastContent;
                    var i = 0;
                    $('#acc_Posts').children().each(function() {
                        accordion = $(this).attr("id");
                        if ($("#" + accordion).hasClass("ui-accordion-header")) {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                first = $(this).attr("id");
                            }
                            lastContent = $(this).next().attr('id');
                            last = $(this).attr("id");
                            if ($("#" + accordion).attr("aria-selected") == 'false') {
                                $("#" + accordion).hide();
                            };

                        }
                        i++;
                    });
                    $("#" + last).css({
                        'display': ''
                    });
                    $("#" + first).css({
                        'display': ''
                    });
```

I try to accomplish when user clicks on the body of active tab that all tabs are being hide except the active and last tab, when user clicks on the last tab all tabs will showup again. Sounds very simple but I cant figure this out.
Maybe somebody had tied to do the same?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To hide or show accordions you must use `collapse`, for example, toggling it:

```
$('#yourAccordion').collapse({toggle: true});
```

Comment: This is about the tabs not the accordion on itselfs